# USB drive not assigned to letter?

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a USB drive that has some files on it, but when i put it in it doesn't show up in explorer. In diskmanagement it shows as "drive 2" but the disk letter is empty. If i try to assign a letter to it, the whole "The operation failed to complete because the Disk Management console view is 
not up-to-date. Refresh the view by using the refresh task. If the problem 
persists close the disk Management console, then restart Disk Manangement or 
restart the computer. " error. How might I do this?

Comment: Well, what exactly have you tried what the error mentioned? Does both the problem and the error persist after boot? Have you checked the event log? What happens when you use the USB drive at another computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'd be getting the files off the drive, and reformatting it ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

i know this question is dead but i recently the same problem and hopefully someone else will stumble on this. go to device manager and right click on the USB mass storage device under universal serial bus controllers and click uninstall on the one that shows up when you plug your device in. unplug device then plug it back in and let it re install drivers for it and it will work again. the usb mass storage device will randomly glitch on random systems resulting in your drive showing up everywhere except my computer.